# sum of the roots of unity

Tags: complex-numbers

$$\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} e^{-j\frac{2\pi}{N}(i + n)k} = \begin{cases} N & \text{for } (i + n) = 0,N,2N,3N, \ldots \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} = N\delta[(i + n)\text{ mod }N]$$

Can someone provide an explanation why the sum is equal to zero if (i+n) mod N is not equal to zero?

Comment: The sum of roots of $x^n-1$ is $0$ by Vieta

Comment: You have been around for almost three years. Haven't you yet noticed that you are supposed to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) around here?

Comment: Do you know what a geometric series is?

Comment: yes I do know what a geoemetric series is @QC_QAOA

Comment: What is Vieta @J.W.Tanner

Comment: See [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta's_formulas)

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1122110/sum-of-nth-roots-of-unity)

Comment: Your sum is a finite geometric series over $k$.

Answer (score 1):

For any polynomial where the coefficient of the leading term $=1$, then the coefficient of the second term is the negative sum of the roots.  Therefore for $z^n-1=0$, the sum$=0$.

Comment: for $n>1$, that is

Comment: @J.W.Tanner You are right, although the question was presented so that it didn't matter.